# Creating new feature file for proclpc.m using mirtoolbox

Tags: matlab

I encounter a problem when creating new function call `mirproclpc.m` from auditory toolbox (`proclpc.m`).

Where suppose this file shall be in use for mirtoolbox.

I get this error:

```
Undefined function 'main' for input arguments of type 'mirspectrum'.

Error in mirfunction (line 193)
        o = main(orig,during,after);

Error in mirproclpc (line 76) varargout = mirfunction(@mirproclpc,orig,varargin,nargout,specif,@init,@main);

Error in demo8classification_prolpc (line 34) proclpc_train = mirproclpc(train);
```

Please help on this.

Comment: What is the function `main`? Where is it defined? Can you call it from the command window, e.g. using `main()` or even `help main`?

Comment: Thank you sir for replying, there is no main() function or file, i'm using mir toolbox 1.4.1

Comment: If possible i can paste my codes here also

Comment: Do you have the whole toolbox in your path?

Comment: I have solve thus problem by creating new file and replace the older one. It helps.